# Uncaught ReferenceError: weight is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.letsCalculateBMI

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this task where I am to build a BMI calculator on specific instructions. I seem to have followed all the instructions except one in `letsCalculateBMI`. The instruction says:

> `letsCalculateBMI` and get it to obtain the selected value from the SELECT element, pass that value to a `getSelectedUser` function call, which should return the `user object` for the selected value. This `user object` should be assigned to a `user` variable.

My confusion stems from how to `getSelectedUser` function call inside `letsCalculateBMI` to return the `user object` and the user object assigned to a `user`.

For a quicker view in `computeBMI` arrow function, the `user` parameter is an immediately destruct to `weight`, `height`, and `country properties`.

Currently the error I have is `Uncaught ReferenceError: weight is not defined     at HTMLButtonElement.letsCalculateBMI`

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" 
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <title>Mini App</title>


  </head>
  <body>    


    <div class="select">
      <select class="select-text">
        <option disabled selected>Select User</option>        
      </select>
    </div>


    <div class="details mdc-elevation--z3">
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-age>Age :</span>
        <span class="value" data-age-value>23 years</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-height>Height :</span>
        <span class="value" data-height-value>169cm</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-weight>Weight :</span>
        <span class="value" data-weight-value>68kg</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-gender>Gender :</span>
        <span class="value" data-gender-value>Female</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="prop" data-country>Country :</span>
        <span class="value" data-country-value>Nigerian</span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <button id="oracle" class="mdc-button" onclick="letsCalculateBMI()">
      Calculate BMI
    </button>
    <div id="outcome">
      <h5 class="mdc-typography--headline5">
        BMI
      </h5>
      <p class ="bmi-text"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
      const users = [];

      const countriesWithLowerBmi = ["Chad", "Sierra Leone", "Mali", "Gambia", "Uganda", "Ghana", "Senegal", "Somalia", "Ivory Coast", "Isreal"];      

      const featToMeter = 0.3048;

      const bmiCountryRatio = 0.82;

      const computeBMI = ({weight, height, country}) => {

        const heightInMeters = height * featToMeter;
        let BMI = weight / (heightInMeters^2);

       if (countriesWithLowerBmi.includes(country)) 
         BMI *= bmiCountryRatio;

       return Math.round(BMI, 2);
      };

      const getSelectedUser = (userId) => {
        return users.find(({id}) => id === userId);
      };

      const displaySelectedUser = ({target}) => {
        const user = getSelectedUser(target.value);
        const properties = Object.keys(user);

        properties.forEach(prop => {
          const span = document.querySelector(`span[data-${prop}-value]`);
            if(span) {
              span.textContent= user[prop];   
            }
        })               
      }

      const letsCalculateBMI = () => {

        const value = document.querySelector('.select-text').value;

        getSelectedUser(value);

        const user = {weight, height, country}
        const bmi = computeBMI(user);

        document.querySelector('.bmi-text').innerHTML = bmi
      };

      const powerupTheUI = () => {
        const button = document.querySelector('#oracle');

        const select = document.querySelector('.select-text');

        select.addEventListener('change', displaySelectedUser);

        button.addEventListener('click',letsCalculateBMI);
      };      

      const displayUsers = (users) => {
        users.forEach(user => {
        const select = document.querySelector('.select-text');
        const option = document.createElement('option');

        option.text = user.name; 
        option.value = user.id;
        select.appendChild(option);
        });
      };


      const fetchAndDisplayUsers = () => {
        users.push(
          {
          age: 40,
          weight: 75,
          height: 6,
          country: 'Nigeria',
          name: 'Charles Odili',
          id: 'dfhb454768DghtF'
          },
          {
          age: 23,
          weight: 68,
          height: 6,
          country: 'Nigeria',
          name: 'Simpcy',
          id: 'gibb12erish'
          }
        );

        displayUsers(users);
      };

      const startApp = () => {
        powerupTheUI();
        fetchAndDisplayUsers();
      };

      startApp();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On this line in `letsCalculateBMI` ~ `const user = {weight, height, country}` ~ `weight` is not defined

Comment: What exactly do I assign to it

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you all you need to know: `weight` isn't defined because, well, you haven't defined it (same goes for height and country). These are *properties* of the user, so you need to get them from the user object returned by `getSelectedUser`.

For example:

```
user = getSelectedUser(value);
computeBMI(user.weight, user.height, user.country);
```

This should fix your problem, but....

> For a quicker view in computeBMI arrow function, the user parameter is an immediately destruct to weight, height, and country properties.

In my opinion, this isn't good OOP design - you've already got an object with all that info; why the need to write more code to split it up?

What I'd rather do would be something like this:

```
...

computeBMI(getSelectedUser(value));

...

const computeBMI = (user) => {

    const heightInMeters = user.height * featToMeter;
    let BMI = user.weight / (heightInMeters^2);

    if (countriesWithLowerBmi.includes(user.country)) 
        BMI *= bmiCountryRatio;

    return Math.round(BMI, 2);
};
```

Comment: Now it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property weight of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at computeBMI (<anonymous>:16:19)
    at HTMLButtonElement.letsCalculateBMI`

Comment: @Chioma Try putting the curly braces around the parameters for `computeBMI`, for example: `computeBMI({user.weight, user.height, user.country})`; or follow the example I lay out at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

letsCalculateBMI should be:

```
const letsCalculateBMI = () => {
        const value = document.querySelector('.select-text').value;
        const user = getSelectedUser(value);      
        const bmi = computeBMI(user);
        document.getElementById("bmi-text").innerHTML = bmi;
};
```